# Wix installer error code 2343 received for a simple configuration. (WIX Newbie)

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer

I am receiving the following error when using the following simple WIX configuration. The application being installed is WPF.

**Product: Web Miner Installer -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , ,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Product Id="*" Name="Application Title" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Avant Prime" UpgradeCode="855a8b6e-c576-41e2-8118-8f3511613478">
            <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

            <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
            <MediaTemplate />

            <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Application Title" Level="1">
                 <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            </Feature>

            <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
            <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />

            <DirectoryRef Id="ShortcutFolder">
                  <Component Id="ShortcutsComponent" Feature="ProductFeature" Guid="{B40F2C3F-CACC-4196-8F8F-C0F6B082404E}">
                        <CreateFolder Directory="ShortcutFolder" />

                        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShorcutFolder" Directory="ShortcutFolder" On="uninstall" />

                        <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct" 
                                  Name="Uninstall xxxxxxx"
                                  Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                                  Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
                                  Directory="ShortcutFolder"
                                  Description="Uninstalls xxxxxxx"/>

                        <RegistryValue Id="RegistryShortcut" 
                                       Root="HKCU" 
                                       Key="SOFTWARE\xxxxxx\settings" 
                                       Name="Shortcut" 
                                       Value="1" 
                                       Type="integer" 
                                       KeyPath="yes" />
                   </Component>
            </DirectoryRef>

            <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
            <Condition Message="This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.5.1 to be installed.">
                  Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45
            </Condition>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
           <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
                  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                         <Directory Id="ShortcutFolder" Name="xxxxxx"></Directory>
                  </Directory>

                  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                         <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="xxxxxxx" />
                  </Directory>
           </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
           <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
                  <Component Id="ProductComponent">
                        <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
                  </Component>
            </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is the requested log information. It is big so I attached a link.

[WIX Installer Error Log](https://avantprime-examples.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com/wix-installer-errorlog.txt)

Comment: Can you provide logs? msiexec /l*v log.txt /i your.msi

Comment: I have added the log to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace INSTALLLOCATION with the real property (INSTALLFOLDER in your case)