# WiX installer error code 2343

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I am receiving the error when using the following simple WIX configuration.

**"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing the package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343."**

I don't understand what is wrong...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<?define ProductName="My Setup Project" ?>
<?define ProductVersion="1.0.0.0" ?>
<?define ProductCode="b7bc7c6f-9a4e-4973-be84-eca8e3427c97"?>
<?define UpgradeCode="1903339e-18bf-42d2-a12c-35e3e487310e"?>
<?define Manufacturer="MyCompany"?>
<Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033"           Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" 
        UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
   <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already       installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutProj" />
</Feature>

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" ></Property>
<!--<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Overridable="yes" Value="License.rtf"/>-->
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutProj" Guid="4CEBD68F-E933-47f9-B02C-      A4FC69FDB551">
        <Shortcut Id="ShortcutProj"
             Name="Proj"
             Description="$(var.ProductName)"
             Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]SetupProject.exe"
             WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"      Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)" Name="installed" Type="integer"      Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the      ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
  <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="b11556a2-e066-4393-af5c-9c9210187eb2">
    <File Id='Proj' DiskId='1' Source='D:\SetupProject\SetupProject.exe'/>
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

this is logfile:

```
=== Logging started: 15.07.2014  16:53:12 ===
Action 16:53:12: INSTALL. 
Action start 16:53:12: INSTALL.
Action 16:53:12: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 16:53:12: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 16:53:12: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: PrepareDlg. 
Action start 16:53:12: PrepareDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0
character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Bigger textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0     character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 16:53:12: PrepareDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 16:53:12: PrepareDlg. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 16:53:12: AppSearch.
Action ended 16:53:12: AppSearch. Return value 0.
Action 16:53:12: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 16:53:12: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 16:53:12: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 16:53:12: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 16:53:12: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:53:12: CostInitialize.
Action ended 16:53:12: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:53:12: FileCost.
Action ended 16:53:12: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 16:53:12: CostFinalize.
Action ended 16:53:12: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 16:53:12: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related     applications
Action start 16:53:12: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 16:53:12: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 16:53:12: WelcomeDlg. 
Action start 16:53:12: WelcomeDlg.
Action 16:53:12: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0     character set, of 14 pixels height.
Action 16:53:13: LicenseAgreementDlg. Dialog created
DEBUG: Error 2343:  Specified path is empty.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may     indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 
MSI (c) (14:DC) [16:53:16:947]: Product: My Setup Project -- The installer has     encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with     this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 

Action ended 16:53:16: WelcomeDlg. Return value 3.
Action 16:53:16: FatalError. 
Action start 16:53:16: FatalError.
Action 16:53:16: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 16:53:17: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 16:53:17: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {1903339E-18BF-42D2-A12C-35E3E487310E}
Property(C): LicenseAccepted = 1
Property(C): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files\My Setup Project\
Property(C): ApplicationProgramsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start     Menu\Programs\My Setup Project\
Property(C): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(C): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLLOCATION
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): TARGETDIR = d:\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): SourceDir = d:\Programming\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\
Property(C): Manufacturer = MyCompany
Property(C): ProductCode = {B7BC7C6F-9A4E-4973-BE84-ECA8E3427C97}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ProductName = My Setup Project
Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(C): WixUI_Mode = InstallDir
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation =     d:\Programming\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\log.txt
Property(C): PackageCode = {3DD7BD4A-C2AF-42D9-A4E0-EF5C649485FA}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\SERGEY
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 7700
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT = 601
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 7601
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 1
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(C): System16Folder = C:\Windows\system\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network     Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder =     C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\SERGEY\Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start     Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start     Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 2980
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 2718
Property(C): LogonUser = SERGEY
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-4221191904-2271210130-3508014703-1000
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1049
Property(C): ComputerName = SERGEY-PC
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1049
Property(C): ScreenX = 1280
Property(C): ScreenY = 768
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 22
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 16:53:17
Property(C): Date = 15.07.2014
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.18408
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7601.17514
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = SERGEY
Property(C): DATABASE =     d:\Programming\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase =     d:\Programming\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = d:\Programming\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = d:\
Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 15.07.2014  16:53:17 ===
MSI (c) (14:F0) [16:53:17:628]: Product: My Setup Project -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (14:F0) [16:53:17:628]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name:     My Setup Project. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer:     MyCompany. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Can anyone advise something ?
I use the Visual Studio 2013

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wix installer error code 2343 received for a simple configuration. (WIX Newbie)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307574/wix-installer-error-code-2343-received-for-a-simple-configuration-wix-newbie)