# Registry Entry not being read in WiX Setup Project

Tags: wix

I have a wix setup project to create an msi file, and I have also created an entry in the registry editor and environment variable, within the same project. I achieved this by using the  and  elements. I am using this msi file as one of the packages for my bundle installer. But when I launch the bundle, I get an error- **"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343"**
I am unsure but I believe it is because the registry entry is not being read properly under the Custom element. I have attached my code for reference.

```
<Property Id="TAPPATHENVVAR">       
  <RegistrySearch Id="TapPath"
                            Root="HKCU"
                            Key="SOFTWARE\ITSOpA"
                            Name="TAP_PATH"
                            Type="raw"/> 
</Property>
    
<CustomAction Id="SetApplicationRootDirectory"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              Value="[%TAP_PATH]"/>
    
<InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="SetApplicationRootDirectory" 
                After="CostFinalize" /> 
</InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like error 2343 is related to your registry entries. Try changing the Directory value "INSTALLLOCATION" to "INSTALLFOLDER" :
[Wix installer error code 2343 received for a simple configuration. (WIX Newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307574/wix-installer-error-code-2343-received-for-a-simple-configuration-wix-newbie)